# Loading a .txt File into a JavaScript Variable without Selecting

Tags: javascript, html, file, text, no-framework

I've asked this question before but did not explain it well enough so here's a better attempt:

I am making an application that will be run **client-side**, not server side. I have a .txt file in the directory with all of the code for the application, and I want to be able to automatically load the contents into a variable without the user needing to select anything. Thus, I do not want to use an `input`, but rather just have the file load itself when the .html page is opened. As an end result, I would want a `String` that contains the text inside the file.

I am not using any frameworks, just strictly coding in JavaScript, CSS, and HTML.

I assume that the answer to this question involves a `Blob` and using `readAsText()`, but even after reading the full documentation I'm unsure how to pass a URL into it so it can read the contents of a .txt file.

Comment: Is this text file served via a webserver? In that case you could use `fetch` to retrieve it.

Comment: @jelhan no it is all local

Comment: What do you mean by "local". How should this text file be served to the client (read: browser)? It may be included in the HTML document or fetched async using `fetch` or the older and less ergonomic `XMLHttpRequest`. But it has to reach the client somehow.

Comment: @jelhan I'm using the js code to parse through the file and organize the data.  I want the file to live in the same directory as the html and js. That way the code can easily reference it. Is this even possible?